# Javascript displaying incorrect date

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently testing out running a server with routes etc. and am trying to display the date of the previous person to request that route. Usually when i use the new Date() object i get it in my local time, but for some reason it is displaying it in UTC (coordinated universal time) and im not sure how to change it.

my code is

```
var date;
var dateArr = [];
var counter = 0;
router.get('/last.txt', function(req, res) {
    counter++;
    date = new Date().toString();
    dateArr.push(date);
    if (counter == 1) {
        res.send("");
    } else {
        res.send(dateArr[counter-1]);
    }

});
```

but i keep receiving the date in the format:
`Fri Mar 26 2021 07:24:50 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)`

Any advice would be appreciated!

EDIT: I live in Australia so i think it usually outputs in AEDT

Comment: Wow...I know that UTC is the French version and in English it's "coordinated universal time" but this might be the first time I've seen CUT being used to refer to it.

Comment: Also, why send the date *formatted* from the server? Usually the server sends timezone agnostic date (UTC/Unix timestamp) and the client formats it accordingly.

Comment: @VLAZ the CUT was typo

Comment: Did you try `new Date().toUTCString()` ?

Comment: @Anurag yeah and it returns "TypeError: date.toUTCString is not a function"

Comment: That's strange, which version of node are you running?

Comment: @Anurag my bad i attatched it to the actual Date() function but it still returns an incorrect time

Comment: @Anurag im not using node directly im using CS50 IDE for uni, so im not sure how to check

Comment: @ikgwin It should work with all the nodejs versions. Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that UTC is the timezone in place for the server where this code is running. That's fine, you can convert that to the local timezone on the client quite easily. Rather than using `toString`, though, I would store either the `Date` object, or its time value (the result of `.valueOf()`), or the result of `.toISOString()` and then send either the time value (a number) or the  ISO string value to the client. That way, you're not relying on the timezone of the server. When you pass either of those (the time value or the ISO string) into `new Date` on the client site, the resulting `Date` will have the same date/time, but because it's operating in the client's timezone, its local time formatting methods like `toString`, `getFullYear`, etc., will use the local timezone of the client.

E.g., change `toString` to (for instance) `toISOString` in your code, and on the client:

```
const dt = new Date(theStringFromTheServer);
console.log(dt.toString()); // Will use the client's timezone to show the date/time
```